# Seaborn catplot combined with PairGrid

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I am playing with the Titanic dataset, and trying to produce a pair plot of numeric variables against categorical variables. I can use Seaborn's `catplot` to graph a plot of one numeric variable against one categorical variable:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(data=train, x='Fare', y='Sex')
```

However, if I try to use PairGrid to graph numeric variables against categorical variables:

```
x_vars = ['Fare']
y_vars = ['Sex']

g = sns.PairGrid(train, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars)
g.map(sns.catplot)
```

It fails with an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-c284a7cfd727> in <module>
      9 #g.map_diag(lambda x, **kwargs: sns.catplot(x, x, **kwargs), jitter=True, kind="bar")
     10 #g.map(sns.scatterplot, y_jitter=1)#, hue=train["Survived"])
---> 11 g.map(sns.catplot)#, hue=train["Survived"])

~/MLProject/book1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map(self, func, **kwargs)
   1363         row_indices, col_indices = np.indices(self.axes.shape)
   1364         indices = zip(row_indices.flat, col_indices.flat)
-> 1365         self._map_bivariate(func, indices, **kwargs)
   1366         return self
   1367 

~/MLProject/book1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in _map_bivariate(self, func, indices, **kwargs)
   1504             y_var = self.y_vars[i]
   1505             ax = self.axes[i, j]
-> 1506             self._plot_bivariate(x_var, y_var, ax, func, kw_color, **kws)
   1507         self._add_axis_labels()
   1508 

~/MLProject/book1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in _plot_bivariate(self, x_var, y_var, ax, func, kw_color, **kwargs)
   1534             color = self.palette[k] if kw_color is None else kw_color
   1535 
-> 1536             func(x, y, label=label_k, color=color, **kwargs)
   1537 
   1538         self._clean_axis(ax)

~/MLProject/book1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in catplot(x, y, hue, data, row, col, col_wrap, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, order, hue_order, row_order, col_order, kind, height, aspect, orient, color, palette, legend, legend_out, sharex, sharey, margin_titles, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   3760 
   3761     # Initialize the facets
-> 3762     g = FacetGrid(**facet_kws)
   3763 
   3764     # Draw the plot onto the facets

~/MLProject/book1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in __init__(self, data, row, col, hue, col_wrap, sharex, sharey, height, aspect, palette, row_order, col_order, hue_order, hue_kws, dropna, legend_out, despine, margin_titles, xlim, ylim, subplot_kws, gridspec_kws, size)
    268         # Make a boolean mask that is True anywhere there is an NA
    269         # value in one of the faceting variables, but only if dropna is True
--> 270         none_na = np.zeros(len(data), np.bool)
    271         if dropna:
    272             row_na = none_na if row is None else data[row].isnull()

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

If I replace `g.map(sns.catplot)` with `g.map(sns.scatterplot)` it does graph successfully without error.

How can I combine `catplot` with `PairGrid`?

Comment: `seaborn.catplot` creates its own figure and places a `FacetGrid` into it. What you try here is hence to create a PairGrid, and for each gridmember create a new figure with a new grid in it. That won't work. So the answer is simple: You cannot combine `catplot` with `PairGrid`. (You may want to try `stripplot` instead though? And if that does not work, provide a [mcve] such that one could actually test it.)

Comment: Is there a solution to this issue? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest already gave the right answer in a comment above: It does not make sense to combine `sns.catplot()` with a separately created `FacetGrid`, because `sns.catplot()` creates its own `FacetGrid` when called.

In any case, `sns.catplot()` invokes another seaborn function to do the actual plotting in each cell of the grid. That function can be selected by specifying the `kind` keyword argument to `sns.catplot()`. The default is `kind="strip"`.

So if you want to manually create a `FacetGrid` and then map `sns.catplot()` to it, but without specifying the `kind`, you may as well use `sns.stripplot()` instead. This does work, but the Titanic dataset is too large for stripplots to be very informative, so I would use violin plots instead:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

num_vars = ['age', 'fare']
cat_vars = ['pclass', 'embarked', 'sex']

g = sns.PairGrid(data=titanic, x_vars=cat_vars, y_vars=num_vars)
g.map(sns.violinplot)
```

[image: facet violin plots]

See the [sns.catplot() documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) for more details.

---

**Follow-up question** by @Bjarne Thorsted:
*How to replace the boxplots inside the violinplots with swarmplots?*

You can still use the same approach, just in this case calling `g.map()` twice. To change the default parameters of the plotting functions to be passed to `g.map()`, you can define modified versions of those functions using the `*` and `**` operators:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

num_vars = ['age', 'fare']
cat_vars = ['pclass', 'embarked', 'sex']

def violin_empty(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['color'] = 'lightblue'
    return sns.violinplot(*args, **kwargs, inner=None)

def swarm_small(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['color'] = 'black'
    return sns.swarmplot(*args, **kwargs, size=1) 

g = sns.PairGrid(data=titanic, x_vars=cat_vars, y_vars=num_vars)
g.map(violin_empty)
g.map(swarm_small)
```

[image: violinplots with swarmplots inside]

Comment: How would I go about replacing the `boxplot`s inside each `violinplot` with a `swarmplot`? I know it can be replaced with `points` or set to `None`, but adding a `swarmplot`, according to the tutorial requires supplying the `Axes` object, which is not possible if the `catplot()` has several `row`s or `column`s.

Comment: @Bjarne Thorsted: I have expanded my answer to include your question. It's not necessary to use an `Axes` object.