# How to remove the extra figures created when running a for loop to create seaborn plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I am trying to do EDA along with exploring the Matplotlib and Seaborn libraries.

The data_cat DataFrame has 4 columns and I want to create plots in a single row with 4 columns.
For that, I created a figure object with 4 axes objects.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, figsize = (16,4))
for i in range(len(data_cat.columns)):
    sns.catplot(x = data_cat.columns[i], kind = 'count', data = data_cat, ax= ax[i])
```

The output for it is a figure with the 4 plots (as required) but it is followed by 4 blank plots that I think are the extra figure objects generated by the sns.catplot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work as intended because `sns.catplot()` is a figure level function, that is designed to create its own grid of subplots if desired. So if you want to set up the subplot grid directly in matplotlib, as you do with your first line, you should use the appropriate axes level function instead, in this case `sns.countplot()`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize = (16,4))
for i in range(4):
    sns.countplot(x = data_cat.columns[i], data = data_cat, ax= ax[i])
```

Alternatively, you could use pandas' `df.melt()` method to tidy up your dataset so that all the values from your four columns are in one column (say `'col_all'`), and you have another column (say `'subplot'`) that identifies from which original column each value is. Then you can get all the subplots with one call:

```py
sns.catplot(x='col_all', kind='count', data=data_cat, col='subplot')
```

I answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922430/seaborn-catplot-combined-with-pairgrid).